# Access to root folder from subdomains (Codeigniter)

Tags: codeigniter, .htaccess, subdomain

I have some trouble to access root dir files when using subdomains:
My css files located in css dir in the root.

```
If i use url "my-site.com/css/file.css" - everything okay
If i use url "en.my-site.com/css/file.css" - 404 error
```

How can i fix it? I don't want to hardcode path to all my css and js files.
Thanks

Comment: have you try to use `base_url('css/file.css');`? it's codeigniter function from `url helper`.don't forgot to load this `$this->load->helper('url')` in your controller

Comment: If you are looking for `.htaccess` solution, try this: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^my-site\.com$ [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.my-site\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.+\.css)$ http://my-site.com/$1 [L]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this for for loading all images, styles, js

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo site_url('css/file.css'); ?>">
```

don't forgot to create directory in your main CI folder.

Answer (score 0):

if you not able to get that like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/file.css">
```

you have a server problems and it is not Codeigniter related ;)

Comment: @loy nice that you fixed ;)